I want to ask about the bad karma of speech when cursing and insulting Buddha and enlightened beings.?
I have a question. When I was a child, about 6 years old, I accidentally said insulting and blasphemous words to the Buddha's name. To be more specific, I said the Buddha's name with vulgar and insulting words. It was a mischievous act of an ignorant child. But later when I grew up and realized my wrongdoing, I deeply regretted it. At that time, I did not think it was a serious insult. Now I am a Buddhist, but I am always worried that it will cause me the retribution of falling into hell? What should I do? I really need advice, thank you and I wish you peace.
P/s: I know Buddha and enlightened beings are very compassionate and will not pay attention to the words of sentient beings. But I still worry about the bad karma of my speech. Maybe this is a silly question but it has haunted me for a long time.

Frist of all, don't worry about it now. It's in the past. Worrying about it only makes it worse. Just let it forget. Just, let it go.

Maybe this is a silly question but it has haunted me for a long time.

Not a silly question. Lot of people has this kind of situations.

By holding on to past wrongdoings, below things happen.

reduces the available time for new good things, good karma
because of worrying is also a small bad karma, by remembering it repeatedly, collects more and more these little bad karmas


You(anyone who is worrying about past little karma) were just a kid.
Just forgive yourself. Be kind to yourself frist. Which is the 1st step in meththa meditation.

I thank you for your advice. I will try to practice good karma and liberation. I wish you peace.
